# The table body will be right-aligned

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using react.
The table will be right-aligned.
I would like to display it in its entirety instead of right-justified. (width: 100%).
I'd like to expand the table so that it's not right-aligned, but full width so that it's the parent element's div tag (width: 84vw).

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-williamson-8x98k?file=/src/App.tsx:0-2066)

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          borderWidth: "2px",
          borderColor: "#C7CED7",
          borderStyle: "solid",
          width: "84vw"
        }}
      >
        <table
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column"
          }}
        >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>boxA</th>
              <th>boxB</th>
              <th>boxC</th>
              <th>BoxD</th>
              <th>BoxE</th>
              <th>BoxF</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody style={{ height: "100px", overflowY: "auto" }}>
            {data.map((d) => (
              <tr key={d.id}>
                <td>{d.a}</td>
                <td>{d.b}</td>
                <td>{d.c}</td>
                <td>{d.d}</td>
                <td>{d.e}</td>
                <td>{d.f}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Remove "display: flex" from table's style.

Comment: Do you want to make `thead` sticky on top?

Comment: If you remove flex, the body will not be scrollable.

Comment: You have to change some structure.

Comment: Change tags and html.

Comment: I don't know what that is, so I asked.

Comment: I will show you some example.

Comment: Add height: "100px" and overflowY: "auto" to the div that wraps the table and remove display  and flexDirection from the table. Also remove the styles from tbody. Let me know !

Comment: thead wants to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-black-zcd12?file=/src/styles.css)

My react code is some similar with your code, and I added css codes to do it.

**Important: if you add `td` instead of `th` in `thead` tag, it doesn't work.

`position: sticky` doesn't work for `thead`, it works for `th`.**

```
.table-container {
  width: 84vw;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 1em 0;
}

th {
  background-color: #99ff99;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #99ff99;
}
```

Comment: I want to add a borderBottom style to thead, but the border does not show up when I add borderBottom.
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I will check it.

Comment: I made red border to th using `::after` pseudo element. Please check the sandbox.

Comment: In `table` element, border works some strange, so I think it's the best way to do it.